# MPI transmission of unknown sub-class with boost::mpi::packed_oarchive and packed_iarchive

Tags: c++, mpi, boost-serialization, boost-mpi

I am trying to transmit a class of of unknown subclass, but known base class.

I believe this should be possible using `boost::serialization`,  `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID` and `boost::mpi`, but I'm pretty new to C++ in general

This is the code that I have:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;


class Action {
protected:
    int start_rank;
    std::string greeting;

    Action(std::string greeting) {
        mpi::communicator world;
        this->start_rank = world.rank();
        this->greeting = greeting;
    };

private:

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & this->start_rank;
        ar & this->greeting;
    };

public:

    Action() = default;

    void invoke() {
        mpi::communicator world;
        std::cout << this->greeting << "! I am process " << world.rank() << " of " << world.size()
            << ". I was created on " << this->start_rank << "." << std::endl;
    };
};


class HelloAction : public Action {

public:
    HelloAction() : Action("Hello") {};

};

class GoodByeAction : public Action {

public:
    GoodByeAction() : Action("Good bye") {};

};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Action, "Action");
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(HelloAction, "HelloAction");
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(GoodByeAction, "GoodByeAction");

int main() {
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;

    HelloAction *hello = new HelloAction();
    mpi::broadcast(world, hello, 0);
    hello->invoke();

    GoodByeAction *bye = new GoodByeAction();
    mpi::broadcast(world, bye, 1);
    bye->invoke();

    world.barrier();

    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::cout << "sending unknown action classes!" << std::endl;
        HelloAction *yup = new HelloAction();
        boost::mpi::packed_oarchive oar(world);
        oar << yup;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "receiving unknown action classes!" << std::endl;
        Action *action = NULL;
        boost::mpi::packed_iarchive iar(world);
        iar >> action;
        action->invoke();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compiling/running with:

```
mpic++ -g -std=c++1y hello.cpp -lboost_serialization -lmpi -lboost_mpi
mpiexec -np 2 ./a.out
```

This seems to run just fine:

```
Hello! I am process 0 of 2. I was created on 0.
Hello! I am process 1 of 2. I was created on 0.
Good bye! I am process 1 of 2. I was created on 1.
Good bye! I am process 0 of 2. I was created on 1.
```

... until getting to the "sending/receiving of unknown action classes", where I get runtime errors:

```
receiving unknown action classes!
sending unknown action classes!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::mpi::exception> >'
  what():  MPI_Unpack: MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind
[machine-name:20194] *** Process received signal ***
[machine-name:20194] Signal: Aborted (6)
[machine-name:20194] Signal code:  (-6)
[machine-name:20194] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x352f0) [0x7fa685cc22f0]
[machine-name:20194] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7fa685cc2267]
[machine-name:20194] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7fa685cc3eca]
[machine-name:20194] [ 3] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x16d) [0x7fa6862fdb7d]
[machine-name:20194] [ 4] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8d9c6) [0x7fa6862fb9c6]
[machine-name:20194] [ 5] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8da11) [0x7fa6862fba11]
[machine-name:20194] [ 6] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8dc29) [0x7fa6862fbc29]
[machine-name:20194] [ 7] ./a.out(_ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_3mpi9exceptionEEEvRKT_+0x80) [0x41426d]
[machine-name:20194] [ 8] ./a.out() [0x413802]
[machine-name:20194] [15] ./a.out() [0x4306e6]
[machine-name:20194] [16] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.58.0(_ZN5boost7archive6detail19basic_iarchive_impl12load_pointerERNS1_14basic_iarchiveERPvPKNS1_25basic_pointer_iserializerEPFS9_RKNS_13serialization18extended_type_infoEE+0x4d) [0x7fa686df5b8d]
[machine-name:20194] [17] ./a.out() [0x41d08d]
[machine-name:20194] [23] ./a.out() [0x40d293]
[machine-name:20194] [24] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fa685cada40]
[machine-name:20194] [25] ./a.out() [0x40cfc9]
[machine-name:20194] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 1 with PID 20194 on node machine-name exited on signal 6 (Aborted).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Questions:

1. Although the question is tagged with `boost`, should it be possible to transmit an unknown subclass at all with or without boost? I understand I could have a registration of sorts by string name, and an inversion of control guy to handle creation, but I thought that was the intent of `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID`.
2. Is there a way to make this work with what I have?
3. Is there a reasonably easy alternative (not using `boost`) to make this work with regular ol' MPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close: Firstly your are missing the actual communication functions for the packed archives. You are trying to extract from the `packed_iarchive` without having received anything into that archive. For instance, you can use `broadcast` as [described](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/broadcast.html):

> with packed archives, the root sends a packed_oarchive [...] whereas the other processes receive a acked_iarchive [...].

However, simply adding the calls to your example will instantiate an `Action` instead of a `HelloAction`. It takes a bit more effort:

- Using base class pointers of non-virtual classes is not a good idea. It may work in your case, because the subclasses are nothing more than different constructors, but it becomes problematic for slightly more complex examples.
- Boost expects the (de)-serialization calls to use symmetric types. You cannot serialize a `HelloAction*` and then unserialize an `Action*`, regardless whether it is a virtual class<sup>1</sup>. If you have to use `Action*` in both cases, you of course also have to use virtual classes, so that boost actually knows the runtime type. Technically you can serialize an `Action*` to a `HelloAction` Object, and then deserialize an `Action*` that yiels the [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/620382) `Action`-part of the original. Again, this works for your example, but it fails for more complex ones and thus is not a good idea.
- You must specialize `serialize` for the sub classes as well<sup>1</sup>.

Putting it all together a working example looks like this:
Note: I added a bit more output to verify that objects are created with the correct types.

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;


class Action {
protected:
    int start_rank;
    std::string greeting;

    Action(std::string greeting) {
        mpi::communicator world;
        std::cout << world.rank() << ": Creating a Action: " << greeting << std::endl;
        this->start_rank = world.rank();
        this->greeting = greeting;
    };
private:

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & this->start_rank;
        ar & this->greeting;
    };

public:

    virtual ~Action() = default;

    Action() { 
        mpi::communicator world;
        std::cout << world.rank() << ": Creating a naked Action" << std::endl;
    }

    void invoke() {
        mpi::communicator world;
        std::cout << this->greeting << "! I am process " << world.rank() << " of " << world.size()
            << ". I was created on " << this->start_rank << "." << std::endl;
    };
};


class HelloAction : public Action {

public:
    HelloAction() : Action("Hello") {
        mpi::communicator world;
        std::cout << world.rank() << ": Creating an HelloAction" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename Archive>  
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) {  
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Action>(*this);
    }
};

class GoodByeAction : public Action {

public:
    GoodByeAction() : Action("Good bye") {
        mpi::communicator world;
        std::cout << world.rank() << ": Creating an GoodByeAction" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename Archive>  
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) {  
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Action>(*this);
    }
};

// It is totally fine to use the EXPORT (without GUID) for MPI
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(GoodByeAction)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(HelloAction)

int main() {
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;

    HelloAction *hello = new HelloAction();
    mpi::broadcast(world, hello, 0);
    hello->invoke();

    GoodByeAction *bye = new GoodByeAction();
    mpi::broadcast(world, bye, 1);
    bye->invoke();

    world.barrier();

    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::cout << "sending unknown action classes!" << std::endl;
        Action *yup = new HelloAction();
        boost::mpi::packed_oarchive oar(world);
        oar << yup;
        mpi::broadcast(world, oar, 0);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "receiving unknown action classes!" << std::endl;
        boost::mpi::packed_iarchive iar(world);
        mpi::broadcast(world, iar, 0);
        Action *action = nullptr;
        iar >> action;
        std::cout << "RTTI: " << typeid(*action).name() << std::endl;
        action->invoke();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Regarding plain old MPI: Sounds like reinventing the wheel to me - certainly possible but not necessarily desirable.

<sup>1</sup> I can't find a definite statement about that in the documentation. This is based on *things go horribly wrong if you try otherwise*. I would appreciate a comment / better answer regarding this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, for some reason I was thinking that since I initialized the `packed_archive`s with `world` the communication was somehow handled (which was dumb, there's more than just `.bcast`!). As for your question about virtual subclass, I found this, but again, I'm pretty new to c++, so I'm not sure I understand it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html (look for `derived_one`)

Comment: Yes, the documentation allows you to serialize non-virtual base class pointers. But that only serializes the sliced base-class-part of the object. Take a look at the various answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/620382) to understand why slicing is dangerous. I have also clarified my answer. What I still fail to read from the documentation is what I have marked with 1 in my answer

Comment: thanks, for some reason I was under the impression that somehow when the deserilaization was happening it would instantiate a correct subclass and only reassign the pointer `action` to point to whatever instance it had created, but I guess that is what I get to figure out how to do!